# Н понимаю почему не выводит в консоль, нужно вывести каждый div, чтобы получилась скороговорка

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
    <div id="string-1">Ядра в вёдра, выдру в тундру!</div>

    <div id="string-2">Выдрав с выдры в тундре гетры</div>

    <div id="string-3">В недрах тундры, выдры в гетрах </div>

    <div id="string-4">Вытру гетрой выдре морду </div>

    <div id="string-5">Тырят в вёдра ядра кедров!</div>

    <div id="string-6">Вытру выдрой ядра кедров</div>



</head>

<body>
    <script>
        console.log(get.ElementById('string-1'));
    </script>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Видимо, вместо `get.ElementById()` вы имели в виду [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

Answer (score 2):

Используйте метод глобального объекта `document` для выбора по `id`. Так вы выберете  объект типа Element соответствующий указанному ID или null, если элемент с указанным ID не найден в документе, а его содержимое доступно через свойство `innerHTML`.

```
console.log(document.getElementById('string-1').innerHTML);
```

[Справка по getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)
[Справка по innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)